# Using Maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have the address to certain location in terms of a string. However i want to convert this address to Lattitude and Longitude. So i used the code given below to convert into geopoint. But this geopoint is not getting added to the map. The map always shows the default map thats the entire world.

```
public GeoPoint getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {

        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> address;
        GeoPoint p1 = null;

        try {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
            if (address == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Address location = address.get(0);
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();

            p1 = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            return p1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return p1;
        }
    }
```

Im new with maps and am not sure what Im doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you know the latitude and longitude, you forgot to update the map to the specific location. You can do it like this:

```
int zoomNiveau = 15;    
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), zoomNiveau));
```

With this code, the map will go to the location of the address. But you need to create a Marker and add it to the map if you want a Marker.

More info about the markers: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker